# Spring Hibernate Forgein Key Constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

i got a problem regarding hibernate and foreign key constraints.

I got the following scenario (pseudo java code). I got a parent class (Department)

```
@Entity
public class Department {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<Person> persons;

  public void addToPersons(Person p) {
    if (this.persons == null) {
      this.persons = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    this.persons.add(p);
    p.setDepartment(this);
  }

  public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

}
```

and a child class (Person)

```
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  private String name;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Person> followers;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "followers")
  private List<Person> following;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Department department;

  public void addToFollowers(Person p) {
    if (this.followers == null) {
      this.followers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    if (!this.followers.contains(p)) {
      this.followers.add(p);
    }
  }

  public void addToFollowing(Person p) {
    if (this.following == null) {
      this.following = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    if (!this.following.contains(p)) {
      this.following.add(p);
    }
  }

  public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person that = (Person) o;
    return name != null ? name.equals(that.name) : that.name == null;
  }

}
```

For completion, the repository class

```
public interface DepartmentRepository extends CrudRepository<Department, Long> {}
```

The controller which causes the exception

```
@RestController
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

  @RequestMapping("/")
  @ResponseBody
  public String index() {
    Department d1 = new Department();
    d1.setId(1L);

    Department d2 = new Department();
    d2.setId(2L);

    Person john = new Person();
    john.setName("John");

    Person alice = new Person();
    alice.setName("Alice");

    john.addToFollowers(alice);
    alice.addToFollowing(john);

    d1.addToPersons(john);
    d2.addToPersons(alice);

    departmentRepository.save(d1); // <-- throws violation exception 

    return "foo";
  }

}
```

I guess it throws the violation exception because the department d2 has not been saved yet, but is it possible to do that without explicitly saving the all entities entites in before?!

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Completed the code. The exception cause:

```
2016-11-24 11:45:40.513 ERROR 19927 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : INSERT on table 'PERSON' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK_R2AEQQXC7UWBN48SHRHMAI8CX' for key (2).  The statement has been rolled back.
2016-11-24 11:45:40.514  INFO 19927 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
2016-11-24 11:45:40.526 ERROR 19927 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause

org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: INSERT on table 'PERSON' caused a violation of foreign key constraint 'FK_R2AEQQXC7UWBN48SHRHMAI8CX' for key (2).  The statement has been rolled back.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.ForeignKeyRIChecker.doCheck(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RISetChecker.doFKCheck(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.normalInsertCore(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.open(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[derby-10.12.1.1.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy69.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.ottogroup.test.MainController.index(MainController.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

Comment: You don't have any `department` here. And could you add methods, and a full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity(name = "department")     
class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    List<Person> person;

    // getter, setter...
}

@Entity(name = "Person") 
class Person {

    @Id   
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idx;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
    private Department department;

    // getter, setter... 
}


Department department = new Department();
Person p1 = new Person();
Person p2 = new Person();

p1.setDepartment(department);
p2.setDepartment(department);

personRepository.save(p1);
personRepository.save(p2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `d.addToPersons(p1);` implementation make sure you set the department to person as well,

```
public void addToPersons(Person person){
 person.setDepartment(this);
 this.persons.add(person);
}
```

same applies to other relationships